# Navbar collapse on mobile - getbootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, android-browser, css

I have a problem with navbar menu in bootstrap on mobile (tested on HTC Wildfire S - default Internet browser)

Here is the problem with resize, when dropdown clicked.

Here is a picture:
[image: after and before images]

The right hand screenshot shows the menu before the dropdown is opened.

The left hand screenshot shows the bad menu size is after the dropdown click. (Default, Static top and fixed top links are invisible)

Tested on "examples" page on link http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the OS on that device? Android? This doesn't seem to be a Bootstrap issue, but one of CSS overflow.

Comment: ANDROID 2.3.5 + HTC Sence 2.1 (Software number: 2.26.401.3)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364241/twitter-bootstrap-3-navbar-dropdown-doesnt-show-all-elements-if-screen-is-small